# Save state of radiobutton to stringlist

Tags: delphi, lazarus

In my application i save some edit value in a Tstringlist with code below:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    F: TStringList;
begin
    SaveDialog1.Filter := 'GPP files (*.GPP)|*.GPP';
    if SaveDialog1.Execute then
    begin
        F := TStringList.Create;
        with F do
        begin
            Add(label7.Caption);
            Add(label21.Caption);
            SaveToFile(Savedialog1.Filename);
            Free;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

I want to save Tradiobutton state too in this Tstringlist. 
Can you help me? 
Regards

Comment: You have bigger problems. Like the fact that you have not named your controls. The fact that you don't use try/finally. The fact that you are using an unstructured file format.

Comment: I have to save the state of radiobutton i mean if checked or unchecked...Maybe there is another easy way to save my date in external file?

Comment: Use an ini file or an xml file to save the state.

Comment: Or JSON or YAML. Anything other than unstructured.

Comment: Can i save the ini file with another extension with savedialog and open it with opendialog?

Comment: File dialogs do not open or save files. They allow you to select file names. Nothing more. What you do with those file names is entirely up to you. I do urge you to step back and improve the basics. You must start naming things. How can you expect success if you have a control named `Label21`. In the Object Inspector, select each of your controls and give them names by setting the `Name` property.

Comment: Radiobuttons come in groups. Saving single ordinal (selected radiobutton's index) per group is enough.

Comment: maybe not is perfect but i solved with Add(booltostr(radiobutton1.Checked)) thanks all

Comment: Not perfect is an understatement. Do you want to learn?

Comment: I'd say "do you want to save yourself hundred of nervous hours when  your client shows you your program does not work, demands money back, and you don't have a clue even where to start searching for the error"

Answer (score 0):

Making an answer just to show the code sample in properly formatted form

To read:

- `try/finally` pattern - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Writing_a_Finally_Block_(Delphi)
- `TIniFile` class and `boolean` values - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IniFiles.TCustomIniFile.WriteBool - as a somewhat outdated with limited capabilities but a very simple text structured format.

So your code would become something like

```
const ini_def_sect = 'Default Section';

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    F: TCustomIniFile;
begin
    SaveDialog1.Filter := 'GPP files (*.GPP)|*.GPP';
    if SaveDialog1.Execute then
    begin
        F := TIniFile.Create(SaveDialog1.Filename);
        try
            F.WriteString(ini_def_sect, label7.Name, label7.Caption);
            F.WriteString(ini_def_sect, label21.Name, label21.Caption);
            F.WriteBool(ini_def_sect, radiobutton1.Name, radiobutton1.Checked);
            F.UpdateFile;
        finally   
            F.Destroy;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Or in VCL with-based style (that many dislike as they dislike `with` statement in Pascal)

```
const ini_def_sect = 'Default Section';

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    SaveDialog1.Filter := 'GPP files (*.GPP)|*.GPP';
    if SaveDialog1.Execute then
    begin
        with TIniFile.Create(Savedialog1.Filename) do
        try
            WriteString(ini_def_sect, label7.Name, label7.Caption);
            WriteString(ini_def_sect, label21.Name, label21.Caption);
            WriteBool(ini_def_sect, radiobutton1.Name, radiobutton1.Checked);
            UpdateFile;
        finally   
            Destroy;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

And you REALLY REALLY should give your variables (including labels, forms, radio buttons, etc) reasonable names while you still can remember a bit about what do each of those mean. Trust me - a month or two and you would forget.

PS: reading the structured file could be something like

```
procedure TMainForm.btnOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    OpenDialog1.Filter := 'GPP files (*.GPP)|*.GPP'; 
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
        with TIniFile.Create(OpenDialog1.Filename) do
        try
            label7.Caption  := ReadString(ini_def_sect, label7.Name, '');
            label21.Caption := ReadString(ini_def_sect, label21.Name, '');
            radiobutton1.Checked := ReadBool(ini_def_sect, radiobutton1.Name, False);
        finally   
            Destroy;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Destroy is fine here, but no good in a destructor. Free works everywhere. I'd sooner you taught a novice to call Free.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan We're not in destructor though. And didn't you saw those `if Assigned(x) then FreAndNil(x)` ? Novices should learn *both the existence AND the difference between* Destroy/Free/FAN rather than just to learn one tool for all situations (and in that case it should be FAN - as having the most functionality)

Comment: I guess you did not understand my point. I had noticed that this was not a destructor.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you wrote "I'd sooner you taught a novice to call Free" and maybe downvoted the answer. I answered that point. I would not teach novice to mindlessly use `Free` or `FreeAndNil` everywhere, i'd rather show both things and hope novice to be curious to search/ask what was the difference

Comment: No down vote from me. I'd sooner you used Free. Because asker is likely to use Destroy and not know any better.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my point is if we consider asker being a proper programmer, then he would see "Destroy" and tell himself "it is something different! i should go and google what is the difference than `Free` and when to use each of those". Or if we would consider him a simplistic copy-paste jockey, then we should  give him `FreeAndNil` instead as having the most functionality of the three methods.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But no one forces him. He can take a sheet of paper and write down the doubts and itches caused by this answer and then address them one after another. Divide and conquer or analysis and synthesis are the principle of self-education. I hope the topic starter is capable of education, but if he is not there is nothing that would aid him in the creative work of programming, which inherently is self-education about every new program domain problems.